# How take the string between two symbols c#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio, substring

In this string output `!re=.id=*2CB=name=xxname123=service=vpn=caller-id=`
I just need this string starting with `*` that is a constant for id that ends in a `=` sign. I've use substring but I notice that the number change to 3 and 4 digits and more. 
My code did not work anymore. I'm triying to make a regex that match only the `.id=XXXX=` string between those `=` sign.

Comment: You tagged the question regex, but did you use a regex? Where is it? What's your code like?

Comment: Rather than describe your code in one big run-on sentence, why don't you just POST IT? Also, saying it "didnt work" tell us absolutely nothing about the problem you're having. Compile error(s)? Runtime exception(s)? Unexpected behavior? BE MORE SPECIFIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this matches what you need but you could try:

```
var myString = "!re=.id=2CB=name=xxname123=service=vpn=caller-id=";
var match = new Regex(@"\.id=(?<value>[^=]*)=").Match(myString);
var id = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```

I haven't tested this for specific syntax, but that should get you just that captured string. You can modify that to iterate across a MatchCollection if you need to do it across a number of items.

```
foreach(var match in new Regex(@"\.id=(?<value>[^=]*)=").Matches(myString) 
{
    var id = match.Groups["value"].Value; //Or do something else with the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks I going to try .

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = " !re=.id=2CB=name=xxname123=service=vpn=caller-id=";
var id = Regex.Match(input, @"\.id=(.+?)=").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This works @"\.id=(.+?)=" but the result give me this for ex: .id=*FFFFFFFE= and I just need "*FFFFFFE" there is a way to clean it?

Comment: @user3104909 No it returns `*FFFFFFE` as expected. See above code. I use the *Value* of *Groups[1]* not *Match*

Comment: Yea right I was testing  it wrong thanks !!!